# Strange problem replacing ", " with "," in Python 3

Tags: python, string, replace

Trying to sanitize some string data where rogue spaces can sometimes creep in, and ran into something bizarre.  I need to make sure none of the commas are followed by a space.  In the sample below, I've deliberately added a space between the Y and its preceding comma:

```
myString = 'X 2751.4, Y 836.0,Z -675.2,A -135.10,B 3.75,C 176.0'
 myString.replace(', ' , ',')
'X 2751.4,Y 836.0,Z -675.2,A -135.10,B 3.75,C 176.07,E1 -2001.43'
 print (myString)
X 2751.4, Y 836.0,Z -675.2,A -135.10,B 3.75,C 176.07,E1 -2001.43
```

You can see that the immediate output of the .replace has done what I want, but the print() shows the rogue space still present.

There must be something stupidly simple that I'm overlooking, but so far, I've had no luck finding it.

Comment: String objects are immutable. `replace` returns a replaced version of the old string. You may want to reassign the result of `replace` in `myString`.

Comment: You have to assign the result of the replace to `myString`

Answer (score 0):

strings are immutable .so you must create new string variable

```
mystring=mystring.replace(', ',',')
print(mystring)
```

Comment: Yeah, I figured that out about 10min after I posted.  Thanks, it's completely obvious in hindsight, but I just don't "think Python" often enough to remember some of these rules.

Answer (score 0):

D'oh!:  use **myString=myString.replace()**

This is what I get for trying to code while I learn....